# How to replace specific fields in mongodb but return the rest

Tags: mongodb, mongodb-query, aggregation-framework

I am not sure the best way to design this.  I have a collection where I want to reinsert into a new collection but I want to keep the structure exactly the same minus a few fields.

```
{
_id: "123",
date: "1900-01-01T11:00:00.0000000",
name: "joe",
birthday: "1999-01-01"
}
```

This could contain other fields that I do not know about - but I know for a fact I want to convert all dates to be ISO Date type - so I only want to be specific to only 4-5 fields out of the possible 20+ fields.

Example of final:

```
{
_id: "123",
date: ISO_Date("1900-01-01T11:00:00.0000000"),
name: "joe",
birthday: ISO_Date("1999-01-01T11:00:00.0000000")
}
```

I was thinking I can create a few new fields with the add option like so:

```
db.collection.aggregate([
//add
{
    $addFields: {
       convertDate: ISO_date(date) ,
       convertBirthdate: ISO_date(date)
     }
},
//
{
    //stuck here
    //select all
    //replace the date strings with the new 
 $project : 
    { 
      //select * but avoid writing each field out as I could miss a few
      *, 
      //replace date with addfields
      date : $convertDate,  
      //replace birthday
      birthday: $convertBirthdate
    } 
}
])
```

Please let me know if this is possible or another more efficient way to do it.

Comment: Is this a one-time shot, how many records are we talking about, and what might be  your strategy to "sniff" string types (e.g. `1999-01-01`) and convert to ISODate?   Try and if it succeeds, "it is a date" else keep it a string?   This would have to apply to *every* field.   Or do you know all the date fields you want to convert?

Comment: Thank you for the comment - yes its a oneshot time but would like to configure it for future uses.  We have about 800K documents.   I do not have a strategy to sniff - my assumption is that they are all dates based off of the servicer dropping the data.  We plan to fix it at the service level but fix current data for now. @BuzzMoschetti

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your direction is correct. You can simply reuse the same field names in `$addFields`. For inserting into another new collection, you may try to use `$merge` or simply `$out`.

```js
db.collection.aggregate([
  {
    "$addFields": {
      "date": {
        "$toDate": "$date"
      },
      "birthday": {
        "$toDate": "$birthday"
      }
    }
  },
  {
    "$merge": {
      "into": "collection2",
      "on": "_id",
      "whenMatched": "merge",
      "whenNotMatched": "insert"
    }
  }
])
```

Here is the [Mongo playground](https://mongoplayground.net/p/e6Eg8ZnhJSc) for your reference.

Answer (score 1):

Here's a one-stage variation that walks the documents attempting to convert any string it finds to a date and if it cannot, it sets it back to the original value and type.  The `$merge` or `$out` would be the same as other answers here.  This is not a nuanced solution but if you know your datestrings are good and nothing else smells like a datestring, then it could be useful.  It is worth noting, however, that if you intend to do a mass conversion as a one-off (or at least rarely and you have millions of documents), it is likely much more efficient to dump the material to disk, process it externally, then use `mongoimport` to bulk re-load the material with multiple threads (the `-j` option).

```
db.foo.aggregate([
    {$replaceRoot: {newRoot: {$arrayToObject: {$map: {
        input: {$objectToArray: "$$CURRENT"},
        as:    "z",
        in:    {k:"$$z.k",
                v:{$cond:[{$ne:["string",{$type:"$$z.v"}]},"$$z.v",
                      {$convert: {input: "$$z.v", to: "date", onError: "$$z.v"}}]}
               }
        }} }
    }}
]);
```

Here is the solution expanded with comments to explain what is going on.

```
db.foo.aggregate([
    // Turn the object into a k-v array named X:
    {$project: {X: {$objectToArray: "$$CURRENT"}}}

    //  Use map to walk the X array.  For each k-v encountered, if the
    //  type of v ($$z.v) is NOT a string, set v = $$z.v (itself), else
    //  use the $convert function to try to make it a date.  If THAT fails,
    //  then convert will use the old $$z.v value.
    ,{$addFields: {Z: {$map: {
        input: "$X",
        as:    "z",
            in:    {k:"$$z.k",
                v:{$cond:{if: {$ne:["string",{$type:"$$z.v"}]},
                          then: "$$z.v",
                          else: {$convert: {input: "$$z.v", to: "date", onError: "$$z.v"}} }}
                   }
                 }}
    }}

    // Turn Z from a k-v array back into an object and "lift" it into
    // the root document.
    ,{$replaceRoot: {newRoot: {$arrayToObject: "$Z"}}}
]);
```

Here is the bigger brother that uses the `$function` operator from version 4.4.  It will recursively walk a document and sniff out Date-like strings and convert them.  It is highly recommended to add an `$out` stage at the end of the pipeline followed by some testing because this can both change many things or miss certain less popular datestring formats.

```
{$replaceRoot: {newRoot: {$function: {
        body: function(obj) {
            var process = function(holder, spot, value) {
                if(Array.isArray(value)) { // test FIRST since [] instanceof Object is true!           
                    for(var jj = 0; jj < value.length; jj++) {
                        process(value, jj, value[jj]);
                    }
                } else if(value instanceof Object) {
                    walkObj(value);
                } else {
                    if('string' === typeof value) {
                        q = Date.parse(value);
                        if(!isNaN(q)) {
                            holder[spot] = new Date(q);
                        }
                    }
                }
            };
            var walkObj = function(obj) {
                Object.keys(obj).forEach(function(k) {
                    process(obj, k, obj[k]);
                });
            }

            walkObj(obj);
            return obj;
        },
        args: [ "$$CURRENT" ],
        lang: "js"
    }}
                   }}
```